# XC16 compiler doubles assembly statements

Tags: c, inline-assembly, xc8

If I enter an in-line assembly statement is C, the XC8 compiler inserts it twice in the code. For example

```
asm("NOP");
```

results in

```
NOP
NOP
```

in the code.

Edit: not just NOPs; every statement is doubled

```
asm("DECFSZ WREG");
asm("GOTO $-2");
```

Results in

```
DECFSZ WREG
DECFSZ WREG
GOTO $-2
GOTO $-2
```

Optimization is off. The code is for a PIC16F1934 microprocessor. We're using MPLAB X.

How do I prevent that?

Comment: The added `NOP` might be for alignment purposes.  Compilers use them for that reason often.....

Comment: First you surely meant XC8, because XC16 cannot compiler for that device.

Comment: Secondly, can you please post more of your code. Is this in a header file or in a C file, and what makes you believe that the instruction is there twice? Have you looked at the binary?

If you look at the LST file it will state the instruction first and follow this by the machine code generated which for inline asm is identical, so it will show the same thing twice even if it generated the instruction only once

Comment: We've removed the assembly code until we find what causes the problem, so right now we don't have a way to show you the produced code. We saw the instructions in the disassembly view. We noticed that each instruction in a pair was at a different address, Yes, XC8, not XC16, thanks.